# Fetch Firebase data from app to website?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have built an iphone app that writes data to firebase. That works fine. Now I want to display that data on a  website. I am totally new to programming, and had to learn swift from scratch.

So  my question is; is there a easy way to display the data on the webpage? It dont have to look  good as long as the data is displayed. I'm not sure if I'm able to learn another codelanguage just yet  ☺

Answer (score 0):

To build a web site you'd use a combination of HTML (for the layout of the web site), CSS (for the actual look of the web site) and JavaScript (for the logic of the web site). JavaScript is indeed a different language, but a second language should be easier than your first one.

I recommend studying the [Firebase Database documentation for JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and taking the [Firebase codelab for web](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They are the best ways to get started with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Firebase JS SDK
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

1. use Nodejs to generate static HTML

or

2. use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) as the website framework, dynamically generate the pages